# Unorthodox article placement

Tags: adjectives, articles, indefinite-articles, such, big-mess-construction

In my English class yesterday we looked at the following example:

> Monica is such a beautiful woman.

We learned that the above sentence could also be written as:

> Monica is so beautiful **a** woman

I am wondering what the rule for this, to me unorthodox, placement of the article before "woman" is.

Comment: Given your username I will assume you are Greek (sorry if you're not). The construct _X is so Y a Z_ is the equivalent to the Greek _X είναι **τόσο** Ψ_ **που**.

Comment: @terdon yes I am Greek. In the example what represents Z in the Greek equivalent? I suppose "woman" but it doesn't make sense after "που".

Comment: _Monica is so beautiful a woman_ == _Η Μόνικα είναι τόσο όμορφη γυναίκα_. In both sentences, in order to stop there (though it is clumsy in English) you would need an exclamation mark. The only way that sentence makes sense is as an exclamation. Otherwise, in both languages you would need a qualifying cause, _Η Μόνικα (X) είναι τόσο όμορφη (Y) γυναίκα (Z) που όλοι την κοιτάνε.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Such* and *so* are degree quantifiers.
*Such* goes before noun phrases and *so* goes before adjectives and adverbs; they're alternants.

Adjectives:

- *She is so good [that she can make anything].*
- *She is so good at carpentry [that she can make anything].*
- *She is so good as a carpenter [that she can make anything].*
- *She is so good a carpenter [that she can make anything].*

Noun phrases:

- *She is such a carpenter [that she can make anything].*
- *She is such a good carpenter [that she can make anything].*

Moreover, *so* and *such* comparisons usually come equipped with a *that* clause, to show just what the standard is for the comparison. That's their normal use.

It's also common in some idiolects to use emphasized ***so*** or ***such*** -- without a *that* clause -- as a general emotional intensifier, like *very* or *extremely*, but with emotional expression. This can be overdone, and is often satirized, especially when attributed to women. But this is conversational use only, not written, especially not in formal writing.

- *She's **so** intelligent.* = *She's extremely intelligent (and that impresses me).*
- *He's **such** a cute little boy.* = *He's a very cute little boy (and I find that endearing).*

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure your teacher said no such thing. The second sentence in your question is not grammatical or, at the very least, clumsy. What you *can* say is

> Monica is so beautiful a woman **that** everyone looks at her whenever she walks by.

The construct *X is so Y a Z* is almost always accompanied by another clause, usually starting with *that*.

---

Some examples:

[Herman Melville, *Moby Dick*](http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/hmelville/bl-hmel-mobydick-37.htm):

> ‘Twas not so hard a task. I thought to find one stubborn, at the least; but my one cogged circle fits into all their various wheels, and they revolve.

[William Shakespeare, *Julius Caesar*](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/juliuscaesar/page_236.html):

> Caesar, now be still. I killed not thee with half so good a will.

Here, the qualifying clause is implied *I killed not thee with half so good a will* **as I now kill myself**.

[The Scots Magazine, Volume IX](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NcsPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=%22so%20strong%20a%22&source=bl&ots=rRfDTUbpAc&sig=x30mmcOngmIqAdinlNX8NnU8geM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D2bEUbGoIYTQ0QXO-oGAAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22so%20strong%20a%22&f=false):

> Since that, the Duke of Parma besieged it in 1587, and found it, even in those days, so strong a place, that in his letters to Philip II. [sic] he complained...

[Edmund Burke, *The Works of Edmund Burke, Volume 2*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=MtEcAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=%22so%20strong%20a%22&source=bl&ots=5CCJglVjey&sig=-SDeACPHpDD4h7FwfIJRS_kc4Cw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D2bEUbGoIYTQ0QXO-oGAAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22so%20strong%20a%22&f=false):

> Nothing is so strong a tie of amity between nation and nation as correspondence in laws, customs, manners, and habits of life.

Comment: Although I haven't had the chance of playing grammar games with a native speaker while growing up, I am under the impression that your example is not grammatically correct. As far as I know, the only correct construct is the first cited by the OP, even when the sentence is followed by another clause introduced by "that".

Comment: +1 for Julius Caesar, my favorite among Shakespeare's works.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius thanks, I only which I could claim to have quoted it from memory. Unfortunately, google was very significant an aid.

Comment: 1) You need to provide the 'qualifying clause' for your Melville quote. 2) In the JC quote it's not 'killed someone else' but 'now kill myself'.

Comment: I think John Lawler covered it in his answer. He demonstrates how either case could be considered correct, whether used as a degree quantifier (with implicit or explicit *that* clause) or as an intensifier (informal). I don't think there's any evidence to conclude the teacher didn't bring this up. Whether is should be in ELL should be a comment. (-1 for now.)

Comment: @StoneyB the Melville quote is what made me change "always accompanied by another clause" to "_almost_ always". Thanks for the JC, haven't read the play in 10 years and was just offering an imaginary clause. Answer updated.

Comment: @Paola, I'm happy to see you here again and partecipating, we need English teachers.

Comment: I tend to agree with Jim and Paola - as a native speaker, both with and without the `that` clause can sound correct, but largely on a case-by-case basis.  Using it with `She is so beautiful a woman` sounds awkward to me.

Comment: @Izkata yes, it does to me as well. That's why I assumed the teacher used a qualifying clause after _woman_.

Comment: The necessity or otherwise of the *that* clause is not relevant to the question. The OP asks 'what the **rule for ... placement of the article** before "woman" is.' This is not an answer to that question. You may like to convert this into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**A/an [noun]** indicates that the noun is a single indefinite/non-specific {noun] from among many [nouns] of that type. It is an example of a class.

OED

> **I. Indicating indefiniteness.**
>
> **1. Used in an indefinite noun phrase referring to something not specifically identified (and, frequently, mentioned for the first time) *but treated as one of a class*: one, some, any (the oneness, or indefiniteness, being implied rather than asserted).**

Consider "This is a cat" - the meaning is "This is an example of a cat" .

If in your sentences, you substitute "one example of" for "a", then you have your answer:

*Monica is such an example of beautiful woman.*

*Monica is so beautiful an example of a woman.*