# Origin of "[noun] enough" instead of "enough [noun]"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Sometimes the word "enough" comes before a noun as in "I've got enough money to waste" and sometimes it comes after as in "I've got money enough to waste". Was "[noun] enough" more common in a particular place or time or with a certain group of people? Why is that the less common form?

Searching for "[n*] enough" on the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows that it appears in all types of writings: fiction, newspapers, movie scripts, etc. "Reason enough", "time enough", and "sense enough" seem to the the most common phrases.

Comment: [Once again](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/117186/15299), _enough_ is a quantifier, and [quantifiers often float](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73985/15299); for instance _each_ in _Each boy denied it_ and _The boys each denied it_. _Enough_ can appear either before or after nouns it quantifies, but there are -- as usual for quantifiers -- lots of idioms, special syntactic conditions, and exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is more common, in most cases, to place quantitiative adjectives before nouns, the juxtaposition of *[noun] enough* provides a bit of style and emphasis.

> He was a character larger than life

has marginally more impact than

> He was a larger than life character

Comment: Your second sentence is a well known idiom, while the first is not. People will tend to say and write the second because it "sounds" right.

Comment: Your example doesn't really relate to the original question, since, as Mari-Lou pointed out, the second sentence doesn't sound right.